# Split a String which do not have a delimiter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have been beating my head around a problem. Following is the input string

```
1034536455702130340053769240340002208520191202134036
```

What I need to do is split this string into the following

```
03453645570
03400537692
03400022085
```

Here, every string that needs to get picked starts with a '03'.

I can do it with a PL/SQL code, by picking each substring starting from a '03' in a loop, then concatenating each value after removing extra characters from left and right and getting only 11 characters in each iteration. And then use REGEXP_SUBSTR to get desired result. However, this approach involves too much code. Is there a way by which this can be achieved using an SQL query?

```
    SELECT UPPER (
              REGEXP_SUBSTR ('03453645570,03400537692,03400022085',
                             '[^,]+',
                             1,
                             LEVEL))
              AS VAL
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('03453645570,03400537692,03400022085',
                          '[^,]+',
                          1,
                          LEVEL)
              IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Would each input string always have exactly 3 matches which start with `03` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your existing code with the original input string, and just change the regex to match `03` followed by 9 digits:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('1034536455702130340053769240340002208520191202134036',
                      '03[0-9]{9}',
                      1,
                      LEVEL)
              AS VAL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('1034536455702130340053769240340002208520191202134036',
                          '03[0-9]{9}',
                          1,
                          LEVEL)
IS NOT NULL
```

Output

```
VAL
03453645570
03400537692
03400022085
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a9d7a7042f95c77674c678224ba3734)

Comment: Thank you @Nick, it's bit slow but it worked like a charm.

Comment: @BurhanKhalidButt - regex is computationally expensive and therefore slow over large volumes of data. Think of it as a tax we have to pay for not storing our data in a proper data model.

Comment: @BurhanKhalidButt unfortunately, as APC says, there's not much you can do about that. It might be useful to take advantage of splitting out the values once to store them separately so that you can speed access in the future.

Comment: @APC Question... do you think Oracle is smart enough not to run the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` twice for each row (i.e., once for the `SELECT`-list value and once for the `CONNECT BY`)?  Would a recursive CTE be faster in a high-volume situation since you could avoid having it evaluated twice per row?

Comment: I evaluated each value one at a time using a for loop and it gave the desired result on 1k dataset in less than a second.

Comment: @BurhanKhalidButt if that's a better result you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Nicks solution. Following is the code that I have used to optimize it. I have evaluated only 1k records and it takes less than 1 seconds. I hope it helps.

```
--Table to store all sorts of strings
INSERT INTO TBL_SCRM_MSISDN
SELECT '0342244357903452274515236320191201091147' NUMBERS FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '03457064700420191201124242' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '03414221723620191201130431' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '1034536455702130340053769240340002208520191202134036' FROM DUAL;


-- Table used to store unique values
create table TBL_MSISDN
(
  msisdn VARCHAR2(500)
);

--Using a loop to evaluate a single value one at a time
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_MSISDN';
  FOR C IN 
    (
    SELECT * FROM TBL_SCRM_MSISDN
    )
    LOOP

        INSERT INTO TBL_MSISDN
        SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (C.NUMBERS,
                      '03[0-9]{9}',
                      1,
                      LEVEL)
              AS VAL
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (C.NUMBERS,
                          '03[0-9]{9}',
                          1,
                          LEVEL) is not null;

END LOOP;
commit;
END;
/


SELECT * FROM TBL_MSISDN WHERE MSISDN IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below query

```
 select  trim(regexp_substr('1$03453645570213$034005376924$0340002208520191202134$036','[^$]+', 1, level) ) value, level
      from dual
       connect by regexp_substr('103453645570213$034005376924$0340002208520191202134$036', '[^$]+', 1, level) is not null
       order by  level;
```

Comment: OP's string does not have embedded `$` characters.